# How to set username and password for webservice type provider?

Tags: c#, web-services, f#, type-providers

I have the following F# code to access a web service using type provider. It got error of missing username when call the web method.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

How to set the username/password? I tried to use the code intelligence to get the properties to set them but I couldn't find them.

```ml
open System
open System.ServiceModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type service = WsdlService<"https://services.....?wsdl">

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let client = service.GetBasicHttpBinding_IXxxDataStorage()
    let forecast = client.GetSomeList("201401") // Error: username not set
     0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do the trick. Sniff around in `ClientCredentials` for various knobs to turn here.

```
client.DataContext.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName <- "user"
client.DataContext.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName <- "password"
```